# How can one find the discriminant of a lattice without using a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

The setup is a lattice $L$, a finitely generated free abelian group with symmetric positive definite integral bilinear form $\langle \ ,\ \rangle:L\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} L\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, for which we have a canonical spanning set $e_x$, where $\langle e_x,e_y \rangle$ is explicitly given. There is a lot of redundancy between these $e_x$ however, and it is not necessarily possible to find a subset of them that is a basis for $L$.

Is there some way to still compute the discriminant/volume of $(L, \langle\ , \ \rangle)$ from this data, without using a basis? By discriminant/volume, we mean, pick a basis $v_i$ of $L$, and look at $\det[\langle v_i,v_j\rangle]_{ij}$.

An example of something similar to this would be computing the trace of a linear map $\phi$ by finding $\phi$ invariant subspaces which span your space, taking the associated complex of vector spaces, and then taking an alternating sum of the traces on these potentially simpler pieces.

An example of a lattice where no two proper subsets of our generators generate is given by $(6,10,15)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A quick thought: Let $M$ (size $n \times k$) denote the matrix whose columns are the canonical spanning elements. I suspect that finding a basis is equivalent to finding a factorization
$$
M = AB,
$$
where the columns of $A$ ($n \times d$) are the basis elements $v_1,\dots,v_d$, and $B$ is a $d \times k$ matrix such that $\det(BB^T) = 1$.

Comment: I suspect that if the above is correct, then the desired volume is the [pseudodeterminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant) of $M^TM$.

Comment: Hermite Decomposition should reduce your vectors to a basis. For your example, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HermiteDecomposition%5BTranspose%5B%7B%7B6%2C10%2C15%7D%7D%5D%5D   where the transposed is used because there are two different conventions for Hermite Normal Form.